# LSTM training error is very high and relatively unchanging

Tags: numpy, keras, lstm

As a learning exercise, I'm trying to use an LSTM model with the Keras framework to predict the stock market based on multiple data points. The size of my input array is roughly [5000, 100]. Based on other questions on this site and articles online, the approach seems fairly standard: put the data in a numpy array, scale it, reshape it to 3 dimensions for the LSTM, split it into train and test sections, and feed it through the model. Running only the training portion of the model, I am consistently getting loss scores around 400,000,000. This is not changed by altering the batch size, the number of epochs, the number of layers, replacing the normalization with dropout layers, changing the sizes of each layer, or using different optimizers and loss functions. Any idea why the loss is so high and what I can do to fix that? Attached is the code. All advice is greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, losses, optimizers, Model, preprocessing
from keras.utils import plot_model
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
features_df = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")

features_np = np.array(features_df)
features_np.astype(np.float64)

scaler.fit_transform(features_np)
num_features=features_np.shape[1]

features = np.reshape(features_np, (features_np.shape[0], 1, features_np.shape[1]))

labels_np = np.array(pd.read_csv("output.csv"))
scaler.fit_transform(labels_np)

test_in = features_np[int(features_np.shape[0] * 0.75):]
test_in = np.reshape(test_in, (test_in.shape[0], 1, test_in.shape[1]))

test_out = labels_np[int(labels_np.shape[0] * 0.75):]
test_out = np.reshape(test_out, (test_out.shape[0], 1, test_out.shape[1]))

inputs = layers.Input(shape=(1, features.shape[2]))
x = layers.LSTM(5000, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
lstm1 = layers.LSTM(1000, return_sequences=True)(x)
norm1 = layers.BatchNormalization()(lstm1)
lstm2 = layers.LSTM(1000, return_sequences=True)(norm1)
lstm3 = layers.LSTM(1000, return_sequences=True)(lstm2)
norm2 = layers.BatchNormalization()(lstm3)
lstm4 = layers.LSTM(1000, return_sequences=True)(norm2)
lstm5 = layers.LSTM(1000)(lstm4)
dense1 = layers.Dense(1000, activation='relu')(lstm5)
dense2 = layers.Dense(1000, activation='sigmoid')(dense1)
outputs = layers.Dense(2)(dense2)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(features, labels_np, epochs=1, batch_size=4)

evaluate = model.evaluate(test_in, test_out, verbose=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

While I have not solved the error, implementing the Sequential() model and using only two LSTM layers and a Dense layer changed the error: the training error is now very low while testing remains high. This now appears to be a (relatively) simple problem of overfitting rather than the more confusing error of high training loss. Hopefully, this helps anyone having a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things i notice and dont understand why you use them. First one is , dense2 layer with sigmoid activation. I dont think sigmoid activation is benefical to when we are trying to solve a regression problem. Can you change that to relu and see what happens. Second one is you have two dense layers. You did not specify that but i think you are predicting two values with same inputs. If you are trying to predict just one value, you should you should change that to

`outputs = layers.Dense(1)(dense2)`